# Python CanOpen Driver over Ethernet

Tags: python-3.x, ethernet, canopen

I am going to develop a python application to manage electrican drivers with CanOpen communication port.
I am going to use CANopen for Python 
https://canopen.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html 
but a can't find any ethernet interface module.
I looked to https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interfaces.html:

The available interfaces are:

```
SocketCAN
Kvaser’s CANLIB
CAN over Serial
CAN over Serial / SLCAN
IXXAT Virtual CAN Interface
PCAN Basic API
USB2CAN Interface
NI-CAN
isCAN
NEOVI Interface
Vector
Virtual
```

It seems there is no ethernet interface.
Who can I build it?

Comment: can is can, not ethrnet... if you plan to use socket can, you need to load kerel modules

Comment: I have to reach all canopen devices through an ethernet adapter.

Comment: The ethernet/canopen gateway is Lenze EMF2180IB.

Comment: have a look to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt

Comment: hum, you are working on Linux, aren't you?

Comment: yes, but a can use windows as well...

Comment: hum.. should have started with that... sorry, I cannot help you with windows

Comment: Ethernet is a different protocol, CANopen for Python can't control it. For example, I have an Arduino it uses TTL(RS232) connect to PC by USB need to convert to SocketCAN.